# Error within coding in my last select statement

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm trying to create coding so that I could output the salary for an employee per month. I'm getting error 1064 which is a syntax error. but I cannot find the error. please help

```
select * from wantlist;

alter table wantlist
add months double,
add years year;

update wantlist
 set months = 1,
     years = "2017"
where wantlist.wantlistno = "WLN005";

update wantlist
set months = 1,
     years = "2017"
where wantlist.wantlistno = "WLN018";

update wantlist
set months = 1,
     years = "2017"
where wantlist.wantlistno = "WLN023";

update wantlist
set months = 1,
     years = "2017"
where wantlist.wantlistno = "WLN053";

update wantlist
set months = 1,
     years = "2017"
where wantlist.wantlistno = "WLN066";


select * from wantlist;
    select staffid, months, years  count(wantlist.staffid) * 100 + 1000 as "Salary"
    from wantlist
    where months = 1
    group by staffid, months, years;
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And why DOUBLE !?!?!!??!?!?!?!?!??!??!?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: You're missing a comma on the second select (after years).  Should be: 
select staffid, months, years, count(wantlist.staffid) * 100 + 1000 as "Salary"